# kinesis data stream bacth size in case of failures

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I have a kinesis data stream mapped to a lambda with batch size 500 and parallelization factor 1(single lambda executing at any time).
what if for some batch consisted of 10 records are fully marked as fail by providing the sequence number of the first record as a response, and in the mean time a new record is added to the stream, my question is for the next lambda execution, **the batch size will be 10(same records from the 1st retrial) or 11?**

Also, is there any documentation related to this?